# How to upload Microsoft word .docx and .xlsx files using Struts2

Tags: struts2

We are using Struts2 in our application and I am using the struts2 upload functionality for file uploading. Now my requirement is, we need to let the user upload to ".docx" and ".xlsx". I listed "application/msword" and "application/vnd.ms-excel" as `allowedTypes` in strut.xml. By this we are able to upload **only** ".doc" and ".xls" files, but **not** ".docx" and ".xlsx" files. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It's doing what you told it. Those mime types are not valid for the docx or xlsx formats. Refer to nmc's answer.

Answer (score 3):

From http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/microsoft-office-2010-mime-types/

The following are the mime types to be used for MS Office 2010 document file formats.

```
.docm: application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotm: application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
.dotx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.potm: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
.potx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppam: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
.ppsm: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
.ppsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.pptm: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.pptm: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.pptx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.xlam: application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
.xlsm: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
.xlsx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltm: application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
.xltx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml
.xps:  application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by validating the file name in the actions that handle the uploaded files. For example:

```
private File attachement;

...
public void validate() {
  if (attachement.getName().endsWith(".docx") || (attachement.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")))
    addActionError(...);
}
```