# How to get the content of an excel file in struts2 after uploading?

Tags: excel, file-upload, struts2, apache-poi

I'm working on Struts2 framework. I need to upload an excel file to the buffer so that I can extract its informations and print them into a table in a jsp page. I followed this tutorial : http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-file-upload.shtml , and so I could upload any type of file. My question is then : how can restrict the type into .xls and .xlsx ? and how can I get the content of the rows existing in the excel file? I read somewhere that i can use the Apache POI API ... but I couldn't get much how to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Struts 2 File Upload Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-file-upload-example-1.html) ?

It shows how to restrict to certain mime types.

You need the mime types described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) for excel.

Comment: To add to this answer, the file type upload restrictions are set in the `struts.xml` config.  Look at the tutorial linked by @VolkerK and look for `<param name="allowedTypes">`.  In addition to the mime types linked above, I posted MIME Types for Office 2010 formats in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10998727/727439

Answer (score 0):

There is an opensource library called jxl. After you haveuploaded your file to your server you can read it in and iterate through ght rows. Its very easy to do.